# Having difficulty with HTML <label> tag

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing a PHP/CSS/HTML code which outputs a webpage which has the logos of companies like Mercedes Benz and Porche. When you click on these logos, a text area appears and you can write your comments in them. My problem is that no matter what I try, the logos are very far apart (vertically) from each other and when you click on an individual logo, the textbox does not appear immediately below or next to that logo -- it appears at the bottom of the page. What I am looking to create is a series of logos which, when you click on it, a textbox appears right below or next to it and then you click on Submit and the data is fed to a database. Can someone please help?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

     <?php

     $number_of_days = 30 ;
     $date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * $number_of_days ;
     setcookie('name', $name, $date_of_expiry );

     ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    img { width:100%; }

    label img {
    transform: scale(0.05);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    }

    label img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0.1);
    }

    input[type='text'] {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    }

    input[type='text']:focus {
    opacity: 1;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

       <label for="mercedesbenz">
       <img src="Daimler Benz logo.png">
       </label>

       <label for="porche">
       <img src="Porche logo.png">
       </label>

       <label for="bmw">
       <img src="BMW logo.png">
       </label>
       <br />

       <form method="post" action="<?php echo
        htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

         <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" alt="HTML5 Icon"    
         style="width:128px;height:128px" placeholder="Merc" />&nbsp &nbsp

         <input type="text" id="Porche" alt="HTML5 Icon" 
         style="width:128px;height:128px" placeholder="Porc" />&nbsp &nbsp

         <input type="text" id="bmw" alt="HTML5 Icon" 
         style="width:128px;height:128px" placeholder="Beemer" />&nbsp &nbsp

         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can u create a http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: You need to post the rendered HTML. Not your PHP. As for your HTML, your inputs are no where near your labels--hence they won't appear under each image.

Comment: also inputs don't have alt attributes.

Comment: Finally, your use of BR tags and NBSP entities makes me believe you maybe don't fully understand proper CSS layout yet. I'd suggest working with someone directly that can help you with the CSS and HTML side of things.

Comment: DA, you're quite right. I've been coding in CSS for just 12 days or so.

Comment: Those images need alt attrs. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, just click the car to add a comment.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f18513hw/

html

```
<div id="form">
       <form method="post" action="#">

    <div class="car">
        <label for="mercedesbenz">
            <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
        </label>
        <div class="comment">
            <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" placeholder="Merc" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
        <label for="porche">
            <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
        </label>
        <div class="comment">
            <input type="text" id="Porche" placeholder="Porc" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
        <label for="bmw">
            <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
        </label>
        <div class="comment">
            <input type="text" id="bmw" placeholder="Beemer" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

css

```
#form {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
.car {
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
}

.car label img {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.car label img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.comment {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;    
}

.comment input {
    width: 128px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.car label img {
    width: 128px;
    display: block;
}

#button {
    position: relative;
    left: 66%;
    margin: 2%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

jQuery/javascript

```
$('.car').click(function() {
    $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");

    var id = $(this).children('label').attr('for');
    var buttonOffset;
    switch(id) {
        case 'mercedesbenz':
            buttonOffset = '0';
            break;
        case 'porche':
            buttonOffset = '33%';
            break;
        case 'bmw':
            buttonOffset = '66%';
            break;
    }

    $(this).children('.comment').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);
    $('#button').css("visibility", "visible");
});

$('.comment').mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
        $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Cristian, I'm so grateful for your contribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your elements close to each other, probably in a wrapping container. So something like:

```
<div>
    <label></label>
    <input></input>
</div>
<div>
    <label></label>
    <input></input>
</div>
<div>
    <label></label>
    <input></input>
</div>
```